# aspnet_regsql SQLCACHEDEPENDENCY

Tags: sqlcachedependency

I have created a datatbase "testschema" and schema called "MySchema". I have
created a table "MySchema.table1" in the database. I am trying to create sql
cache dependancy on table using aspnet_regsql utitlity.
MySchema.Table1
But it throw an error.
Enabling the table for SQL cache dependency.
An error has happened. Details of the exception:
Cannot create trigger
'dbo.MySchema.Table1_AspNet_SqlCacheNotification_Trigger'
as its schema is different from the schema of the target table or view.
Failed during cache dependency registration.
Please make sure the database name and the table name are valid. Table names
mus
t conform to the format of regular identifiers in SQL.
The failing SQL command is:
dbo.AspNet_SqlCacheRegisterTableStoredProcedure
I have tried with out schema name and again it is failed. Pl. let me know
what's wrong creating dependancy on table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it !

http://forums.asp.net/t/1249281.aspx/1

The problem occured if you have more other schema on your db (other than [dbo])
after the change made to the sp AspNet_SqlCacheRegisterTableStoredProcedure
to select the schema dynamically it worked!

Thank you Vivek